# Web application not registering in Firebase project console

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-console

In my project console, I get this message.

> There are currently no apps in the project FancyProject

I then receive the instructions to include Firebase in a script tag in my application.

However, I have already included it in my React application as the following and I have checked to make sure that it registers. I am also able to update my Firebase database as well in my application with no problems. How come this doesn't get added as an app in my project console?

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'

export const config = {
  apiKey: "<APIKEY>,
  authDomain: "<AUTHDOMAINLINK>,
  databaseURL: "<DATABASEURL>",
  storageBucket: "<STORAGEBUCKET>",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDERID>"
}


let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
console.log(app.name) // this registers!


export const ref = Firebase.database().ref()
export const firebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
```

Answer (score 8):

This is expected behavior. Only iOS and Android apps are added in the list of apps in the Firebase Console. The web link/snippet is purely shown there as an easy way to access the settings for your web app.

Comment: I get this `Your project has no apps sending data to BigQuery`. Does this mean my web app is actually sending data to BigQuery even though it's not an "app", per se? Im confused because I have a data set Im trying to send over. Im trying to link Firebase and BigQuery together

Comment: When you link Firebase and BigQuery together, Firebase will send over its Analytics data. Given that there is no Web API for Firebase Analytics, what data do you expect your web app to be sending to BigQuery?